# Multiple Function Events/Callbacks?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to create a function that passes back the events from a Firebase upload function, and then show the progress in my UI

I have a function, that handles the uploading of an image like so:

```
import firebase from '~/firebase';
import hashSum from 'hash-sum';
import events from 'events'

async function uploadFile(image, design) {
  const eventEmitter = new events.EventEmitter();
    const hashId = hashSum(image.name + Date.now())
    const meta = {
      customMetadata: {
        namne: image.name
      }
    }
    const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref().child(`designs/${firebase.auth().currentUser.uid}/${design.id}/${hashId}.png`);
    const task = storageRef.put(image, meta);
    task.on('state_changed',
      (snapshot) => {
        const percentage = snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes * 100;
        eventEmitter.emit('progress', percentage)
        console.log(percentage)
      },
      (err) => {
        eventEmitter.emit('error', err)
      },
      () => {
        task.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(url => {
          eventEmitter.emit('done', {url, hashId})
        })
      }
    )
}



export { uploadFile }
```

And then in my UI I want to receive these events and do something with them:

```
const upload = await uploadFile(selectedFile, {id: this.props.match.params.id})
upload.on('done', async (data) => {
  files.push({id: data.hashId ,name: selectedFile.name, url: data.url})
  await firebase.firestore().collection('designs').doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).collection('designs').doc(this.props.match.params.id).update({
    files
  })
})
upload.on('error', (err) => {
  message.error(err)
})
upload.on('progress', (percent) => {
  this.setState({
    uploadProgress: percent
  })
})
```

Now clearly I'm doing something wrong as `upload.on` is not a function.  Can anyone advise how to handle this, or if there is an easier way to return an already existing event?

Comment: looks like you are getting a `Promise` back and using `async`, shouldn't you `await` the function?

Comment: I've edited my post, but maybe I'm doing something wrong?  Referencing the function doesn't appear to work still